# AngularJS $destroy never gets fired?

Tags: angularjs, scope

In angularJS, I want to do something when a scope is destroyed, when I searched on line, I came cross this page: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2548-Don-t-Forget-To-Cancel-timeout-Timers-In-Your-destroy-Events-In-AngularJS.htm?&_=0.5475860409906698#comments_44655

I made a little change to the code as below, but the $destroy does not seem to be fired. after I close the browser tab or go to another URL, I did not see anything in the console window.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ng-scope" ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="DemoController"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>
        Don't Forget To Cancel $timeout Timers In Your $destroy Events In AngularJS
    </title>
<style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak{display:none;}ng\:form{display:block;}</style></head>
<body>

    <h1>
        Don't Forget To Cancel $timeout Timers In Your $destroy Events In AngularJS
    </h1>

    <p>
        <a href="#" ng-click="toggle()">Toggle Section</a>
    </p>

    <div ng-switch="section">

        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: happy -->

        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: sad -->

    <p class="ng-scope" ng-switch-when="happy" bn-directive="">
            Oh sweet!
        </p></div>


    <!-- Load jQuery and AngularJS. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://bennadel.github.io/JavaScript-Demos/vendor/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://bennadel.github.io/JavaScript-Demos/vendor/angularjs/angular-1.0.7.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        // Create an application module for our demo.
        var app = angular.module( "Demo", [] );


        // -------------------------------------------------- //
        // -------------------------------------------------- //


        // I control the main demo.
        app.controller(
            "DemoController",
            function( $scope ) {

                $scope.section = "happy";

                // I toggle the section value, to show/hide the
                // differnet sections in the markup.
                $scope.toggle = function() {

                    if ( $scope.section === "happy" ) {

                        $scope.section = "sad";

                    } else {

                        $scope.section = "happy";

                    }

                };

            }
        );


        // -------------------------------------------------- //
        // -------------------------------------------------- //


        // I'm just a sample directove to demonstrate the clearing 
        // of a $timeout event in the AngularJS $destroy event.
        app.directive(
            "bnDirective",
            function( $timeout ) {

                // I bind the User Interface events to the $scope.
                function link( $scope, element, attributes ) {

                    // When the timeout is defined, it returns a 
                    // promise object.
                    var timer = $timeout(
                        function() {

                            console.log( "Timeout executed", Date.now() );

                        },
                        2000
                    );


                    // Let's bind to the resolve/reject handlers of
                    // the timer promise so that we can make sure our
                    // cancel approach is actually working.
                    timer.then(
                        function() {

                            console.log( "Timer resolved!", Date.now() );

                        },
                        function() {

                            console.log( "Timer rejected!", Date.now() );

                        }
                    );


                    // When the DOM element is removed from the page, 
                    // AngularJS will trigger the $destroy event on 
                    // the scope. This gives us a chance to cancel any
                    // pending timer that we may have.
                    $scope.$on(
                        "$destroy",
                        function( event ) {
                            $timeout.cancel( timer );
                            console.log( "Timer Canceled!", Date.now() );
                        }
                    );

                }

                // Return the directive configuration.
                return({
                    link: link,
                    scope: false
                });

            }
        );


    </script>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The destroy event will be fired if you stay in the angular application, but navigate to another route and thus destroy the scope associated to the current controller (for example).

If you close the tab, this is basically equivalent to pulling the plug: the angular application itself ends completely.

Comment: thanks. Is there any way to do some tearing down things right before that?

Comment: Why? You've killed the entire execution context and all associated memory is thus released by the browser...

Comment: @JohnDing you can try to use the ònbeforeunload` event handler: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload for your teardown tasks

Answer (score 0):

The element's '$destroy' event is fired when the element is removed from DOM. After removing DOM I find it necessary to destroy the scope also, otherwise scope alives.

```
element.on('$destroy', function(){
    scope.$destroy();
});
```